# Компонент новостей, Не отображается кнопка добавить новость, как исправить? Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Компонент новостей, кнопки в публичной части Изменить, Удалить выводятся, а вот Добавить элемент не выводится, права доступа полные, инфоблок активен, как пофиксить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужна кнопка добавить новость как здесь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если выводить просто список новостей, то кнопка присутствует, если комплексный Новости, то кнопка пропадает

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Здравствуйте, вопрос дополнил

Comment: Картинки никому не нужны... Сделай тестовый пример с иллюстрацией проблемы и покажи его тут в песочнице.

Comment: @ksa, это комплексный компонент Битрикса - какой пример в песочнице Вы хотите увидеть?

Comment: Дело не в моем хотении... Проблема-то не у меня. Если хочешь помощи - учись правильно задавать вопросы чтобы нашлись желающие тебе помочь. Вот собственно и все...

Comment: @ksa, никакой песочницы здесь не надо вопрос понятен и так, наверное вам не стоило просто отвечать, раз не знаете как помочь

Comment: @Nikita, сейчас под рукой Битрикса нету, но попробуйте нажать каретку рядом с шестрёнкой - по идее должен выпасть список простых компонентов, которые входят в состав комплексного, и там будет какой-нибудь news.list, и уже у него в свою очередь должна быть опция "добавить"

Comment: @humster_spb В шестеренке же просто настройки компонента
У меня получилось решить проблему так: 
Я заметил, что при выборе раздела (1 скрин разделы сверху например "транспорт", "здоровье") этот плюсик есть, зашёл в папку комплексного компонента и взял код из section.php и вставил в news.php
и визуально ничего не поменялось, а кнопка добавления появилась

Comment: @Nikita, так я и не про шестерёнку говорил, а про каретку рядом :) Но если удалось решить проблему, ок

Comment: Проблема может быть в том, что если раздел не указан, то непонятно, в какой раздел добавлять новость. Поэтому в section.php автоматически новость попадает в нужный раздел. А теперь нужно будет выставлять раздел вручную, иначе новость попадёт неизвестно куда.